# How to call the very first (top level) coroutine in C++ program?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

We can not `co_await` from non-coroutine, so, we can not do something like that:

```
void main(void)
{
  co_await my_coroutine();
}
```

Let suppose that `my_coroutine` is something that we don't control directly and can not create its callback-based version. So how to call it at all?

Naive idea is something like that:

```
void main(void)
{
  my_coroutine();
}
```

It will not work of course, because we'll exit `main` before `my_coroutine` will finish.

So what to do? One working idea will look like that:

```
void main(void)
{
  auto my_promise = my_coroutine();
  bool my_promise_finished = false;
  while(!my_promise_finished)
  {
    /* somehow detect indirectly/in undocumented way that my_coroutine finished */
    my_promise_finished = is_my_promised_finished();
    Sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

The idea is ugly. 1. We have to use undocumented/unreliable way to detect whether coroutine finished. 2. We block entire main thread to wait while another thread will do something.

Are there any good/official way how to call the very first/top coroutine in C++ program and wait for its completion without blocking entire thread for that job.

The example is practical enough. For example, we may have URL download utility that calls single top-level coroutine `download_1000_urls` and it may create multiple threads on its own and download a lot of data from Internet; it is still single top-level coroutine that `main` has to call somehow, similarly to old-style asynchronous `Application.Run` method.

Comment: "*It will not work of course, because we'll exit `main` before `my_coroutine` will finish.*" There's no way to know that. It all depends on what `my_coroutine` is doing and what its return value represents.

Comment: There are no official ways to call the top coroutine. You can do this as you please. However with more complex programs you will probably have to run them on top of some event loop like libuv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the C++20 coroutine feature does implement "coroutines", these are not like "coroutines" that you may see in other languages. I mean, they are, but not in the way you're thinking.

For this question, the most important thing is this: a coroutine is an *implementation detail* of how a function works.

Your `my_coroutine` is not actually a coroutine from the perspective of any code that is not *inside* of `my_coroutine`. It's just a function. Like any other function, it takes some number of parameters, performs some operation, and provides some kind of return value to the caller.

As such, if a function is a coroutine, and that coroutine wants to pass some delayed value or control mechanism to its caller, the only interface it has is the *return value* of the function. That is how external code interacts with the coroutine. If the return value so allows it, it can provide a mechanism to check to see if it is completed and to continue the coroutine if it isn't. It can provide a mechanism to request the next value for generator-style coroutines. It can do a *lot* of things.

But in all of these cases, it is up to the coroutine itself to provide those interfaces. There is no one-size-fits-all answer for how you "control a coroutine". In a real example, `my_coroutine` will return some object and members of that object are your control mechanism. Whatever interfaces it provides are how you control it.

So if `my_coroutine` is some multi-step process, and `my_coroutine` expects the caller of it to tell it to execute the next step, then `my_coroutine` needs to return an object that facilitates this. Alternatively, if `my_coroutine` registers itself with some asynchronous facility which will automatically resume it once that process it is waiting on has completed, then `my_coroutine`'s return value won't have a way to execute the next step because that's someone else's job.

The interface a particular function provides tells you how to interact with it. There is no uniform interface because there are dozens of ways to use a function that can be paused and resumed. You build the interface that your particular use case needs.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library provides such a mechanism for waiting for asynchronous operations: the C++11's async model (`std::future` and `std::promise`). While it can't be used out-of-the-box with C++20 coroutines, you can easily add this functionality yourself.

Based on the [std::coroutine_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_traits) example from cppreference:

```cpp
// A user-defined type
struct as_coroutine{};

// "Assign" a valid coroutine promise object to std::future 
template<>
struct std::coroutine_traits<std::future<void>, as_coroutine> {
    struct promise_type : std::promise<void> {
        std::future<void> get_return_object() {
            return this->get_future();
        }
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept {
            return {};
        }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept {
            return {};
        }
        void return_void() {
            this->set_value();
        }
        void unhandled_exception() {
            this->set_exception(std::current_exception());
        }
    };
}
```

And you can wait for the result with the `std::future` mechanism

```cpp
std::future<void> wait_my_coroutine(as_coroutine) {
    co_await my_coroutine();
}

int main() {
    // Wait for result or an exception if any occurred
    wait_my_coroutine({}).get();
    return 0;
}
```